# Google Analytics Spam on Mobile - App Not Released

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics

Across multiple Google Analytics accounts there seems to be an outbreak of spam.  Lots of events posted similar to the one below:

> EVENT CATEGORY: to use this feature visit: EVENT-TRACKING.COM

Now for web, I can add a filter to block by hostname.  Not perfect, but doable.

But what about mobile?  I have an app I haven't even released yet getting these spam events. So these guys aren't crawling sites and spamming, they're actually just guessing Analytics account numbers and using the API.

Can anything be done about this?

Seems to me like Google Analytics needs to start using API keys for mobile apps.  At least then the spammer would have to download your app and decompile it before they can spam you.

Answer (score 1):

I found some info,it may be useful.

http://blog.analytics-toolkit.com/2015/guide-referrer-spam-google-analytics/

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/7qJIbsK-svA