# Google Analytics Got Spam On Mobile Application

Tags: android, google-analytics, referrer-spam

Recently I got all of my applications spam on Google Analytics as in picture:

[image]

all spam from Macintosh, which is not possible because this is an Android App.

I saw this post: [Google Analytics Spam on Mobile - App Not Released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287251/google-analytics-spam-on-mobile-app-not-released)

but I don't see any relevant answer.

**does anyone know how to remove spam?**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select a new checkbox option which would be included in the view level of the management user interface. This option would be labeled "Exclude traffic from known bots and spiders".

See:  [Guide](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAnalytics/posts/2tJ79CkfnZk)

Comment: thanks.  can it remove retro all spam? rigth now i still see all span statistics...

Comment: @itzhar i don't know this..but you can check into the management user interface. If you have happy for the answer you can accept :)

Comment: anyway, this is not help at all. still have spam

Answer (score 0):

finally i found solution:

you can add any filter:

go to Admin -> select your Account & property -> Filters -> add custom filter

in my case i exclude all results from Operation System Platform -> 'Macintosh Intel 10\.10' (USE AS REG EXP)