# Google Analytics how to stop spam events when using Mobile Analytics?

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, spam-prevention, referrer-spam

My question is very similar to this one: [Google Analytics Spam on Mobile - App Not Released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287251/google-analytics-spam-on-mobile-app-not-released) I'm using mobile iOS analytics client, so all of my events are coming from mobile devices.

**What filter setting would make Google Analytics reject all events and sessions that don't originate from a mobile client?**

I've looked at articles like this one: [how to stop referrer spam](http://www.ohow.co/stop-www-event-tracking-com-referral-spam/), and solutions don't seem to apply to me, since none of my analytics events should be coming from websites.

Analytics spam registers calls from all kinds of countries, devices, etc. Specifically there are events with category "to use this feature visit: EVENT-TRACKING.COM"

```
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:tUIAction     
                                                          action:tButton  
                                                           label:sender.identifier
                                                           value:nil]
                   build]];
```

Comment: Probably better to ask this in the Webmaster forum.

Comment: I've updated code to show how I send events. Is there something I can use with the API to uniquely identify my own legit events?